# vertical and horizontal div centering and efficient css

Tags: css, header, alignment, footer, centering

pretty new to web design and I thought it would be a good idea to create a basic mockup of a website with a header, a paragraph and a sticky footer just to ensure I've got some basics down :)

I'm wondering how to center the .paragraph div vertically as well as horizontally and also if there are any obvious problems or inefficiency with the code that I should be aware of. I just want to make sure I can code a basic layout without developing bad habits.

So I ended up with this css:

```
.head {
margin: auto;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: #000;
color:white;
text-align:center;}

body {
    background-color:#99C;
}


.h1 {
    font-size:50px;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    padding:30px;
}



.paragraph {
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#333;
    width:35%;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:165px;
    padding:10px;

}



* {
  margin: 0;
}


html, body {
  height: 100%;
}


.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -70px; 
}


.wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}


.site-footer, .wrapper:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 70px; 
}


.site-footer {
  background: orange;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:40px;
  line-height:70px;

}
```

And here's how it looks:

[image]

Thanks in advance!!!

Adam H

Comment: So what exactly is your question? The image doesn't demonstrate a problem.

Comment: I'm sure you will get some helpful answers for this but I'd just like to add.. In terms of efficient code, it varies for each website. That's the main skill that should be worked on, changing code to suit each situation. Browser support is a big thing to consider and making sure your code works properly on the browsers you expect your users to use. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: well mainly I'm wondering about centering the paragraph div vertically in the body, I've been looking around on other posts here and elsewhere and it kind of surprises me that the only solutions I can find require adding extra container divs around the one that you want to center. Seems crazy to me, but anyhow thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

what about when you need to change the header/footer height for some reason?
you'll need to alter more than one rule in your CSS to keep your layout as you want it.

Here's the same layout that you desire, without fixing any height, using pure CSS.
<kbd>[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/Mspxt/5/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Header">
        <p>I'm in the header</p>
        <p>my height is not fixed</p>
    </div>
    <div class="HeightTaker">
        <div class="Wrapper Container Inverse">
            <div>
                <div class="Footer">
                    <p>I'm in the footer</p>
                    <p>my height is not fixed</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="HeightTaker">
                <div class="Wrapper">
                    <div class="Content">
                        <div>
                            <p>I'm in the content</p>
                            <p>I always span the rest of the page.</p>
                            <p>If my content is bigger than my available space, I will scroll</p>
                            <p>This Layout has been tested on: IE10, FireFox, Chrome, Safari, Opera using Pure CSS only</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body, .Container
{
    height: 100%;
}
    .Container:before
    {
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
    }
.HeightTaker
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
    .HeightTaker:after
    {
        content: '';
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
.Wrapper
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.Inverse, .Inverse > *
{
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.Header
{
    /*for demonstration only*/
    background-color: #bf5b5b;
}
.Content
{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    /*for demonstration only*/
    background-color: #90adc1;
}
    .Content:after
    {    
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .Content > div
    {
        font-size: medium;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

.Footer
{
    /*for demonstration only*/
    background-color: #b5a8b7;
}
```

Notice: the only Downside in my approach, is that I have to construct the footer before the content (in the HTML).

Comment: Ah ok this is interesting, I've had a little mess around with this to see whats going on and I'm going to continue in the morning (im in UK and it's like 1am here). Just wondering though, I can see that without the '.Inverse, .Inverse > *' webkits etc the footer appears above the content, but I'm not sure why. What's the function of this?

Comment: the technique that stretchs the content to take all the available height of its parent works only if you try to stretch the last element in the container. so I had to make the middle div last in container in the HTML, and then reverse it in the view using CSS.